# if statement depends on existence of data in array, but how to not lose first item in array upon checking it?

Tags: php, mysql, is-empty

It's reminding me of that one question about if the cat exists and it only exists if you open the box. But I digress.

I'm checking the result of a mysql query to find out if a column has data in it, if so I will list the data under a heading. It appears that the act of checking it is "using up" the first in the set of three results in the array that I would otherwise want to display. Here is what I mean:

My query in this case results in the names of three children: Billy Timmy and Sally. I want their names to appear under a heading, "CHILDREN." But sometimes there are no children so I don't want a heading in those cases.

Here is a code sample, missing lots of other content, but I think this is what's pertinent.

```
<?php
$query2 = SELECT name AS ChildName
          FROM family
          WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bday, CURDATE()) < 24
          AND familyid = ".$_GET['id']."";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

   <?php $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ?>
   <?php IF(!empty($row2['ChildName'])) { ?>
   <strong>CHILDREN</strong>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { ?>
   <ul> <?php echo '<li> ' . $row2['ChildName'] . '</li>';?> </ul>
   <?php } ?>
```

My result in this case is:

CHILDREN

Timmy

Sally

But if I take out the heading check I get all three names under the (permanent) heading.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if any rows are returned using `mysql_num_rows($result)` method and then do the while loop getting and displaying all the rows. Now you're not getting the first row because you are fetching it to check if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, nothingman, that was just what I needed. That makes sense with the whole "fetch" thing.

For anyone seeing this in the future, the result looked like this:

`<?php if (mysql_num_rows($result2)) { ?>
<strong>CHILDREN</strong>
<?php } ?>`